# Uniform convergence and second derivative

Tags: uniform-convergence

let $u(x)$ be a function in $C^2(\mathbb R)$.

Define $u_n$ by

\begin{align*} 
u_n(x) = u\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)  + u\left( - \frac{x}{n}\right) - 2u(0)
\end{align*}

then,

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^N u_n
\end{align*}

uniformly converges on $[-a, a]$, where $a > 0$.

I know the definition of uniform convergence. And, I just tried transforming $\sum_{n=1}^N u_n $ to $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n^2} n^2u_n$ , because $n^2 u_n(x) \rightarrow u^{\prime \prime } (0)$. However I have no idea what to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Use MVT twice to show that $|u_n(x)|=|[u(\frac x n)-u(0)]+[u(-\frac x n)-u(0)]|$ is bounded by a constant times $\frac  1{n^{2}}$. [You will need the fact that the continuous function $u''$ is bounded on $[-a,a]$]. It now follows by M-test that $\sum u_n$ is uniformly convergent.

Comment: I find that $|u_n(x)|\leq \frac{c}{n}|x|$, so in $[-a,a]$ wouldn't the bound simply be a constant times $\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: @tmaj Apply MVT to each of the two terms and then apply MVT again. Note that if $u$ is between $0$ and $\frac  x n$ and $v$ is between $-\frac   x n $ and $0$ then $|u-v| \leq \frac {2x} n$.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Thank you!! I understand it.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy when I apply MVT for the first time on the two terms, I get $|u_n(x)|\leq |\frac{x}{n}|[|u'(\alpha)|+|u'(\beta)|]$ where $\alpha \in (0,\frac{x}{n})$ and $\beta \in (-\frac{x}{n},0)$. I don't know what I should be applying MVT to again. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Write $|u'(\alpha)-u'(\beta)|$ instead of $|u'(\alpha)|+|u'(\beta)|$.